# Install Commerce 2 direct to server with Composer and SHH without Git

Tags: git, drupal, commerce

I would like to install Commerce 2 on my Drupal site.
I have composer installed and am trying to Composer 2 via SSH directly to my server. But I get an error...

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

[RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://git.drupal.org/project/coder.git, git was not found
  , check that it is installed and in your PATH env.
  sh: git: command not found

Does it want me to have git on my local machine? I have installed it but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any help will be highly appreciated =0)

Comment: You have to setup it locally and clone the repository in it, then make it live.

Comment: Ok will do, thank you @ Chandraveer